# matlab - unknown array dimension bubble sort

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix, multidimensional-array

I tried to build a function that sort a matrix with an array dimension.
I mean the array of N-by-M-by-W-.........by-Z
the sort is bubble sort.

I faced 2 problems:

1st - In the way I know of bubble sort. I could sort a matrix so that each row will be sorted but not the entire matrix. If I have been asked to bubble sort the array, should I sort the entire matrix or maybe even the entire array or bubble sort on arrays is just working on the rows?

2nd - and the bigger problem I have is that my thought is stuck because I build a function for 2dim , 3dim,4dim and each time I had to add one more for, but I couldn't find a solution for the unknown case since it will take unknown fors.

I have seen a solution here on stackoverflow for a different task but with the same unknown dim array but I haven't fully understood it.

I added here what I did so far in 4 dim but I think it is pretty bad. Here is the code:

```
if ( ismatrix(D) )

cycles=ndims(D);

for w=0:cycles-1   %% number of times needs to sort triple dim matrix
    for z=1:row-1     %minimum nubmer of times the proccess needs to run in order to get fully sorted two dim matrix
        for j=0:(col-2)
            for i=1:row
                if(  D((i+j*row)+(row*col*w) )>D( (i+j*row+row)+(row*col*w) )  )
                    temp=D((i+j*row)+(row*col*w) );
                    D((i+j*row)+(row*col*w) )=D((i+j*row+row)+(row*col*w) );
                    D((i+j*row+row)+(row*col*w) )=temp;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I wanted to apologize for my spelling mistakes it is 4 am now and i am tired.
I couldnt find the edit button but I forgot to mention [very important ] that I must build the code without using the sort function.

Comment: The edit button is right above the comments section and at the bottom of your post... underneath the tags.  You can't really miss it.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work

Comment: Question:  Why are you using linear indexing when multidimensional indexing is more easier to read?  Specifically, why aren't you doing `D(i,j,w)` for example?

Comment: yes now I see the edit button . I guess I didnt find it because of the late hour.
I actually not sure why I use linear indexing, I think it is because the only other language I know is C so every problem I have I try to solve it like I would solve it in C and then translate it to matlab . this is obviously not a good way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question looks like an assignment, so I will not give you a solution, rather some pieces knowledge you will need for a solution.

Use subscripts instead of linear indices.
As  rayryeng already mentioned, you can index for example first row, second column using `D(1,2)`. To select a full column, you also need the `colon` operator: `D(:,2)`

Mix subscript indices and linear indexing to iterate over all columns. Just for demonstation purposes a pice of code which prints all columns in a n-dimensional matrix:

```
M=rand(3,2,1,2);
[rows,e]=size(M);
for idx=1:e
    disp(M(:,e))
end
```

You may need to read the documentation for `size`, `colon` and "Matrix Indexing"

Finally just a shortcut. To swap index a and b in a matrix, use `M([a,b])=M([b,a])` which obviously can be combined with subscript indices for other dimensions: `M([a,b],idx)=M([b,a],idx)`

Comment: thank you .
You are right and this is my mini assignment  in the assignment   I have been asked to bubble sort this unknown array but it is not clear if I should sort it row wise or maybe the all array. is there any chance you might know?

Also
 'code' 
 M([a,b])=M([b,a])
'code' 
wont swap a and b but will run over [a,b] with [b,a] value won't it?

In addition will it be efficient if I'll do something with M(:) ?
but then again I go back to linear indexing

Comment: @maor: How should I know what your assignment is? Regarding the swapping: Try it with simple examples, it swaps index a with index b. How it works is explained in the "Matrix indexing" section of the documentation.